# Dense set meaning on this proof...

Tags: general-topology

Theorem: Let $f$ and $g : X → Y$ be continuous functions (Open Set Definition of Continuity). Assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff and  that there exists a dense subset $D$ of $X$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x ∈ D$.  Prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x ∈ X$.

Proof: Suppose not; say there is some $x∈X$ with $f(x)≠g(x)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, we may find open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ separating $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, i.e., $f(x)∈U$, $g(x)∈V$, and $U∩V=$∅. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f‾¹(U)$ and $g‾¹(V)$ are open in $X$ and non-empty (since $x$ is in both); let $N=f‾¹(U)∩g‾¹(V)$. 
Now $N$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and for all $y∈N$, $f(y)≠g(y)$, since $f(y)∈U$ and $g(y)∈V$. But this contradicts the density of $D$; therefore, $f(x)=g(x)$ for all x∈X.

My question: I don't understand the "But this contradicts the density of $D$". According to the same book, a subset $D$ of a topological space $X$ is called dense if $Cl(D) = X$. How is it concluded that the "$N$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and for all $y∈N$, $f(y)≠g(y)$, since $f(y)∈U$ and $g(y)∈V$" can't be true if "$Cl(D) = X$"? Why it is necessary that $D$ to be dense? What is the relationship? I thought on it for times and times but I don't understand it; I am new in topology, please if someone explains it, a clear explanation I need!

Only clue I have is that there is no open set as a subset of $D$ because of $Int(D)=$∅ and it is because of $D$ is dense, but still connection of this to the proof is not clear for me.

Thank you.

Comment: would be that: "Prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$"?

Comment: Yes! I edited it. Thanks

Comment: Theorem is from "Introduction to Topology - C. Adams and R. Franzosa". The proof is from https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080213141432AAwPKP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $D$ is dense in $X$ (indeed meaning $\operatorname{Cl}(D) = X$) iff for every non-empty open set $O$ of $X$ we have $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$. (Left to right: let $x \in O$, then $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(D)$, and $O$ is an open set containing $x$, so $O$ intersects $D$; right to left is similar).

And we have just witnessed a non-empty open set $V$ that does not intersect the supposedly dense set $\{x \in X: f(x) = g(x)\} \supseteq D$ of $X$ (as all elements of it have *different* image under $f$ and $g$).

Put slightly differently: $V$ is open and non-empty, and cannot intersect $D$ (as points of $D$ have the same image under $f$ and $g$), so $D \subseteq X \setminus V$, and the latter set is closed and $\neq X$, so the closure of $D$ is not $X$, contradiction. But the writer of this proof clearly had the above alternative formulation of being dense in mind.

Comment: Very beautiful! Thank you. Just about the 1st paragraph (left to right), how you conclude that if $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(D)$ (and of course $x \in O$ and $O$ is open) then $x \in D$? Right to left is clear.

Comment: Not $x \in D$, but $O$ intersects $D$. A point is in the closure of $D$ iff every neighbourhood of it intersects $D$.